# Is the Fourier Transform of the limit the limit of the Fourier Transform?

Tags: limits, reference-request, integral-transforms

Assume you want to compute the Fourier transform of a function $f_\epsilon(x)$ given by

\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f_\epsilon)(k) = \int f_\epsilon(x) e^{-ikx}\, dx
\end{align}

Further assume, that $f_\epsilon \rightarrow f$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

My question is:

Does
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0 }  \, \, \mathcal{F}(f_\epsilon)
=
\mathcal{F}(\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0 }\, \, f_\epsilon)
\end{align}
hold true?
What are the necessary assumptions on $f$ and $f_\epsilon$. It would be nice to have some references.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I apologize very much for not beeing specific enough. Indeed, my function behaves nicely and convergeces uniformely.

Comment: It is not really possible to answer your question, since it is not precisely formulated. How do you interpret the convergence $f_\epsilon \to f$? Pointwise convergence (a.e.), uniform convergence, convergence in some $L^p$ space, convergence in the sense of tempered distributions? The same holds for the convergence of the Fourier transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways that make this thing hold true. The first one, also the useless one, is that $f_{\varepsilon}\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}^n$. An other thing should verify the hypothesis of dominated convergence theorem. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
What I want to say is that your problem is not very much different from the problem of taking the limit under the sign of the integral. 
And, moreover, one has to be more precise in the statement of the last equality in your question. For example, if your function is in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ then your equality is just an almost everywhere equality, while if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a pointwise equality, because its Fourier tranform must be continuous...

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that $f_\epsilon(x) e^{-ikx}$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Vitali convergence theorem. The dominated convergence theorem can be viewed as a practical way to check the VCT hypotheses.

Comment: If $f\in L^1$ i agree with you! But what if $f\in L^2$ for example?

Comment: At least at each point separately, the situation is the same, just use the $L^2$ version of the VCT. But you're right that a bit more theory is required in the $L^2 \setminus L^1$ context for the FT. But unfortunately the OP did not specify what sort of convergence they want for the FT (pointwise, a.e., $L^1$, $L^2$, ...)

Comment: Yes. He should have been more precise.

Comment: I juse wanted to emphasize that $f_\epsilon \to f$ uniformly does **not** impliy $\hat{f_\epsilon} \to \hat{f}$ pointwise. To see this, consider $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[-n,n]}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ uniformly, but $\widehat{f_n}(0) = \int f_n \, dx = 2$ for all $n$.